# Java: Listen to directory change on a remote Linux server

Tags: java, linux, spring, nio

I have a Spring web application which triggers a SAS job on a remote Linux server, the SAS job will generate a result file on the remote server upon finished. I need to display the result on my Spring application, so I want to create a listener for the directory changes on the server.

I have being looking at the java.nio library, but it looks like it only works local directories. Any ideas other than keep pinging the server through ssh? Thanks!

Comment: You could install a service which is listening for directory or file changes on the remote server which will inform you about changes. These notification can happen in many ways, i.e. by mail or by invoking a further service, ... Not sure though, if the remote server is under your control

Answer (score 0):

You might use [FTP from org.apache.commons.net.ftp](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html)

Using FTP (or any other Java FTP library), you only need to check for the content on the remote directory.

If the directory supposedly is always empty, then when the first file appears your process will be triggered.

If the directory is not always empty, you might need to implement something to control which files are new, and which are not.

Please let me know if you need further assistance.